# How to integrate flex with existing web app?

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications

I'm having trouble conceptually understanding how to integrate flex components -- forms, charts, data grids, etc. -- with an existing web app. There are certain aspects of the web application where I believe it makes more sense to use flex -- however, I DO NOT want to replace the (html/js/java) web-app with a pure flex based app.

For example, currently the web app displays user data using html tables and java based charts, I'd like to re-implement this "data display" using flex.

1. Would I have to create a flex "application" for the "data display"?
2. What if I wanted to re-implement the forms used by the web app to save the data in flex, would I have to create a flex "application", separate from the "data display" flex app?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Would I have to create a flex "application" for the "data display"?

Yes!  Anything you want to use flex, you need to create a Flex application.

> 2. What if I wanted to re-implement the forms used by the web app to save
>      the data in flex, would I have to
>      create a flex "application", separate
>      from the "data display" flex app?

In theory, all this would be embedded in the same Flex Application.

It sounds to me like you're thinking of flex using the same "page" metaphor that is used in web sites.  This is not recommended.  Think of a Flex app like a self contained entity.

You wouldn't want a situation where you are loading multiple Flex apps on a page.  If that is what you were thinking, you should reconsider.  You probably don't want a web site with a new Flex app on every page either.  If that's what you're thinking, I believe there are AJX equivalents for most Flex Components.  Take a look at those.

Comment: Apparently, I haven't grasped how a flex app is 'supposed' to be constructed. You're correct that I thought it was similar to the 'page' concept, where each flex app should/would correspond to a single function i.e. display or form. 

However, if I treat a flex app as an 'entity' and include all the needed forms and displays for my web app into the a flex app, how can/should I show the correct flex form or display when the user navigates to a particular page? Should I use BrowserManager?

Comment: BrowserManager is for changing the URL of the application as you change the application's state.  

With HTML you have pages.  With Flex apps you have states for the most part and states change the UI based on some action, such as clicking a button to move to a different 'view'.  Many people use navigator classes, such as a ViewStack or TabNavigator.